# TRichViewEdit Paragraph Number

Tags: delphi, properties, delphi-xe2, paragraph

There are extensive properties in the `TRichViewEdit` component to find most properties of a given paragraph.  For instance, you can easily tell if a paragraph uses numbering, what type of numbering it uses, if it starts numbering at a specific number or is a continuation of the previous paragraph, etc.

However, I can't find a property or method to determine the paragraph number that is in use.  For instance:

```
A. some text
B. more text
C. etc
```

I can't tell that `some text` is paragraph number `A`, that `more text` is number `B`, and that "etc" is 'C'.  It would be okay if I could access numeric values too, like '1', '2', or '3'.

Does anyone have experience with `TRichViewEdit` and know how to get the paragraph numbering value?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.trichview.com/help/index.html?idh_class_trichviewedit.html), there's information available about what type of list it is, but nothing specific to the value of the list item.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite.  That's my conclusion too.

Comment: This example on the docs might give you a hint on how to do it http://www.trichview.com/support/trichview.support.examples/example_movingcarettotheparagraph.htm

Comment: @GuillemVicens, I tried that, but it didn't provide access to the paragraph number itself -- just the text after the paragraph number.  I contacted the component maker.  There is an undocumented way to do it.  I'll post that as the answer.  Thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

There is an undocumented way to do this.  If `rve` is the `TRichViewEdit` component and `ItemNo` is the id of the item number of the paragraph with numbering:

```
use
  RVMarker;

TRVMarkerItemInfo(rve.RVData.GetItem(ItemNo)).Counter; // paragraph number as int
TRVMarkerItemInfo(rve.RVData.GetItem(ItemNo)).DisplayString; // displayed paragraph number
```

### Example

```
use
  RVMarker, TypInfo;
---
var
  i, lno, ll, sf: Integer;
  usf: Boolean;
  rvmii: TRVMarkerItemInfo;
  pi: TParaInfo;
  s: string;
begin
  for i := 0 to rve.ItemCount - 1 do
  begin
    if rve.RVData.GetItemStyle(i) = rvsListMarker then
    begin
      pi := rve.Style.ParaStyles.Items[rve.GetItemPara(i)];
      rve.GetListMarkerInfo(i, lno, ll, sf, usf);
      s := GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TRVListType), Ord(rve.Style.ListStyles.Items[lno].Levels[ll].ListType));
      rvmii := TRVMarkerItemInfo(rve.RVData.GetItem(i));

      ShowMessage(
        Concat(
          'Paragraph Info',                                      #13#10,
          '---------------------------------',                   #13#10,
          #09'OutlineLevel:',    #09, IntToStr(pi.OutlineLevel), #13#10,
          #09'ID:',           #09#09, IntToStr(pi.ID),           #13#10,
          #09'Index:',        #09#09, IntToStr(pi.Index),        #13#10,
                                                                 #13#10,
          'Marker Info',                                         #13#10,
          '---------------------------------',                   #13#10,
          #09'ListNo:',       #09#09, IntToStr(lno),             #13#10, // can also use 'rvmii.ListNo'
          #09'ListLevel:',       #09, IntToStr(ll),              #13#10, // can also use 'rvmii.Level'
          #09'StartFrom:',       #09, IntToStr(sf),              #13#10, // can also use 'rvmii.StartFrom'
          #09'UseStartFrom:',    #09, BoolToStr(usf),            #13#10, // can also use 'rvmii.Reset'
          #09'Counter:',         #09, IntToStr(rvmii.Counter),   #13#10,
          #09'DisplayType:',     #09, s,                         #13#10,
          #09'DisplayString:',   #09, rvmii.DisplayString,       #13#10,
                                                                 #13#10,
          'ItemText',                                            #13#10,
          '---------------------------------',                   #13#10,
          rve.GetItemText(i+1),                                  #13#10  // next item is text for para #
        )
      );
    end;
  end;
end;
```